# ArcGIS JavaScript v3.17 - Spatial query to find out how many line features intersect polygon feature

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am working on a tool using ArcGIS JavaScript v3.17 to perform a spatial query to find out how many line features intersect a polygon layer.  The process works for 1 polygon layers but does not work for the other 3 polygon layers (results in an error).  The error I get is: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when the query is ran, which doesn't tell me much about what is wrong.  See sample code below.  Has anyone else seen this before?  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function submit() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        query;
    });
}
function query() {
    var polys = map.getLayer('lyr1');
    var lines = map.getLayer('lyr2');
    var queryTask = new QueryTask(lines.url);
    var query = new Query();
    query.geometry = polys.graphics[0].geometry;
    query.spatialRelationship = esri.tasks.Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
    query.outFields = ['*'];
    queryTask.on("complete", queryTaskExecuteCompleteHandler);
    queryTask.on("error", queryTaskErrorHandler);
    queryTask.execute(query);
}
function queryTaskExecuteCompleteHandler(queryResults) {
    console.log("complete", queryResults.featureSet.features.length);
}
function queryTaskErrorHandler(queryError){
    console.log("error", queryError.error);
}
```

Comment: Check the url, which is being passed to the query. The error message say that there is an '<' character passed for query.

Comment: The url is what it should be with no '<' characters

Comment: You get the above mentioned error when the service for some reason fails and returns a HTML response, and the JSON parser tries to parse that and throw the exception as it would not be able to parse HTML tags. Hope this info would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my issue by going a different route and am now using the geometryEngine intersects process to find out if a line intersects a polygon.  This involves a for loop that goes over a list of each line graphic > runs the intersects process comparing the polygon feature to the line graphic geometry > if true, the id gets pushed to an array > will use that array to get a total and also a definition expression on the line features.